# Can this function be implemented?

Tags: function, haskell

Is there any implementation for this function?

```
foo :: (Monad m, Monad n) => m a -> n a -> (a -> a -> a) -> m (n a)
foo x y f = ...
```

Comment: besides the trivial `\_ na _ -> return na`?

Comment: yeah I'm looking for a function that applies `f` somehow

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, and it can be given a more general type.

```
foo :: (Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> g b -> f (g c)
foo f fx gy = fmap (\x -> fmap (f x) gy) fx
```